# How to handle BizTalk POST while exposing schema as REST service?

Tags: rest, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a BizTalk application where I have exposed schema as a RESTful web service, which calls another REST service. I am able to successfully handle GET, DELETE request.

Is there a way to handle POST request without writing a pipeline component to serialize the POST request to a schema?

Also, the application may have to handle several POST calls, so will it be possible to serve this from one single receive location and then filtering the request on the send port?

Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: What format of data is being posted?   You can use <BtsHttpUrlMapping> in the HTTP Method and URL Mapping in the WCF-WebHttp Transport properties in BizTalk 2013 R2 to map the Method & URL to a Operation.  I'd have to look at what you can do in BizTalk 2013.   So yes, please add more details about payload & how you expect to differentiate the POSTs

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the thing.  You're mixing together some things that technically have nothing to do with each other.

For instance, a Plain Old Xml (POX) service, usually a POST, does not 'expose' a Schema in the way a SOAP service does.  It just takes whatever content is POSTed to it.

Following that, serialization/deserialization is also a concept more related to SOAP that POX or REST.

So...

1. Yes, but what exactly are you doing?
2. Yes.  A plain http endpoint can accept any content type.  Once it's over the wire, all the normal BizTalk processing rules apply.